# pgfplots + animate: Incorrect math mode symbols (unwanted verbatim)

Tags: pgfplots, animate

### Description

I want to make an animated diagram. As soon I use the animate environment the stuff in math mode (`$...$`) is not displayed correctly (looks like verbatim text with `_ ^` and so on).

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article} % standalone article

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section*{Normal Diagram}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            ymin=0,
            ymax=20,
            xmin=-5,
            xmax=5, 
            xlabel={$\text{test}^1_2$},
                ]
    \addplot[] {x^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\section*{Animated Diagram}

\begin{animateinline}%
[
controls,
% Begin -------------------------------
begin=
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                ymin=0,
                ymax=20,
                xmin=-5,
                xmax=5, 
                xlabel={$\text{test}^1_2$},
        ]       
},
% End -------------------------------
end={
    \end{axis}  
    \end{tikzpicture}   
}
% Loop -------------------------------
]{15} % Frame Rate in Hz
\multiframe{5}{rMyReal=1+0.1}
{
    \addplot[] {\rMyReal*x^2};
}
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

### Visualization

[image: Problem]

### Update

This is a reply to [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg)'s answer. Thanks for the help. I am just wondering because I did a animation in 2013 (the same code basically) and it just worked. Here's the PDF (see slide 28 and 29).

[Link: PDF with Animation](http://bipede.de/Downloads/Statistik.Kuehner.(2013)_2013-03-01.pdf)

> Was there a change in the `animate` package?

[image]

[image]

Here's a screenshot from the original code (it still compiles correctly):

[image]

Comment: There have indeed been changes to `animate.sty`; IIRC, some settings leaked outside the `animateinline` environment.

Comment: @egreg: I think I should contact the developer of the animate package. Using math mode in pgfplots seems to be a very common request. Thanks again. In the screenshot of code above you see that I have a lot of $...$ in the xticklabels option. It's not practical in my opinion to use your solutions here.

Comment: Fixed in version `[2015/08/18]` available tomorrow. Thanks once more for finding this bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It was a bug (Fixed in version [2015/08/18]), see comment of AlexG.

Here's the output (same code just updated version of `animate` package):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `animateinline` calls a “sanitization macro” that changes all special characters (excluding braces and backslash) to printable characters.

There are two ways around this.

### A save box

```
\newsavebox{\animatecaption} % in the preamble

\sbox{\animatecaption}{$\text{test}_{1}^{2}$}
\begin{animateinline}
  [
   controls,
   % Begin -------------------------------
   begin=
    {
     \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                ymin=0,
                ymax=20,
                xmin=-5,
                xmax=5,
                xlabel={\usebox{\animatecaption}},
        ]
  },
  % End -------------------------------
  end={
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
```

### `\scantokens`

```
\begin{animateinline}
  [
   controls,
   % Begin -------------------------------
   begin=
    {
     \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                ymin=0,
                ymax=20,
                xmin=-5,
                xmax=5,
                xlabel={\scantokens{$\text{test}^1_2$\noexpand}},
        ]
  },
  % End -------------------------------
  end={
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sorting this out! Originally, I wanted to sanitize the colon '`:`' char, which may appear in the `buttonfg` and `buttonbg` command options, in case the `french` babel option was set by the user. I considerably extended the list of characters to be sanitized when I added JavaScript support which may occur in the timeline file, in order to correctly read JS code from that file.  In the next version,  while reading the command and environment options, only the colon's catcode will be fixed. The full list of special chars is sanitized only when the timeline file (with JS code) is read.